# Implement Row_number () over (partition by colname) in talend

Tags: talend

How do I implement `Row_number () over (partition by colname)` for the below data in Talend??

```
Product_Category Product_Item
100 A123
200 B678
200 B234
100 A456
200 B345
```

Can this be done in tmap component?

Comment: what is your source of data ..if its database, it will be easier to get this row_number() done in tDBXInput component..

Comment: Source is a file n destination also a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Numeric.sequence function to accomplish this.

ex: 
tFixedFlowInput -> tMap -> tLogRow

Steps.

1. within the tMap, define a variable, like seq
2. The variable should be of type int
3. The formula for the variable will use Numeric.sequence, with the product category as the sequence identifier
   ex:
   Numeric.sequence(row1.product_category,1,1)
4. put the seq on the output of the tmap, as well as the other two source columns
5. Send the output to something else, like a tLogRow

Using your sample data, here is the output

```
.----------------+------------+---.
|            tLogRow_1            |
|=---------------+------------+--=|
|product_category|product_item|seq|
|=---------------+------------+--=|
|100             |A123        |1  |
|200             |B678        |1  |
|200             |B234        |2  |
|100             |A456        |2  |
|200             |B345        |3  |
'----------------+------------+---'
```

https://help.talend.com/display/TalendDataIntegrationStudioUserGuide61EN/E.1+Numeric+Routines

Comment: Thank you, this worked but what if I need to work on order by another column will that be possible? For example, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) .. till now we have just achieved row_number() over (partition by)

Comment: Also, the order by has to been done on a date column to pull the records which are of the latest date.

Comment: You can certainly change the order . If you sorted by product item , before the tMap, it still works and you'll get the sequence numbers assigned slightly differently. Ex: B234 will get seq 1.

Answer (score 0):

there's an issue here where I apply the numeric sequence to input.. my output which just has a sequence row added turns out messed

I want my row number to start from 2 with an increment of 1 on the basis of column invoice so in the variable field I created a variable as var_rw and defined it as Numeric.sequence(Invoice, 2,1) and pointed it to the rwnbr column as Var.var_rw

But my output is coming wrong :( if you see the output, if I have two invoices it skips one number and numbers it as 4.

Invoice     code     actual      expected
i123           ASD           4           2
i123           DFG           5           3
i234           DTH           6           2
i234           RDF           7           3
i234           SDF           8           4
i234           WES          9           5

Comment: Apologies for the format of the output .. I'm posting from my cellphone .. so I'm not able to format it right